# Espaçamento entre parágrafos html

Tags: html, css

A princípio quero dizer que sou iniciante na área, comecei a cursar recentemente Sistema de informação e minha pergunta é para realização de um trabalho valendo nota.

ao utilizar a tag:

```
<p>primeiro parágrafo</p>
(este espaço precisa ser reduzido)
<p>segundo parágrafo</p>
```

Porém meu professor ainda não iniciou o conteúdo de CSS e não o verei antes da data de entrega do trabalho, se não houver solução sem a utilização de CSS peço que expliquem como fazer, pois realmente ainda não tenho noção de como se introduzir CSS no código html.

Comment: Você já tentou pesquisar algo sobre o assunto?

Comment: Sim, pesquisei, porém não achei nada em html simplificado, mas já resolvi com uma das dicas de um colega do site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se está limitado a não usar CSS, o que poderia fazer é usar um paragrafo só e separar com uma quebra de linha simples.

Assim:

```
<p>primeiro parágrafo<br>segundo parágrafo</p>
```

Resultado:

> primeiro parágrafo
>   segundo parágrafo

---

Em contra partida, usando CSS, temos o seguinte: Todo o browser adiciona regras de estilo próprias aos elementos comuns. O Google Chrome, por exemplo, define essas regras:

```css
p {
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
}
```

Já o Firefox faz assim:

```css
p {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Visualmente o efeito é o mesmo: adicionar uma margem ao elemento `<p>`. A forma mais simples e melhor portável entre diferentes browsers é usar o [**`normalize.css`**](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Ele contém regras para desfazer as regras padrões de todos os browser e deixar o estilo único. Use assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css">
```

Alternativamente você pode zerar todas as formas de margem do elemento com essa regra:

```
<style>
  p {
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Ou aplicada assim:

```
<p style="margin: 0;">primeiro parágrafo</p>
<p style="margin: 0;">segundo parágrafo</p>
```

Comment: Guilherme, não estou limitado a utilizar o CSS, porém não acredito que como acadêmico seja interessante eu utilizar um código que eu não seja capaz de entender, pois não adiantar eu tirar nota máxima no trabalho e reprovar por não saber o que está na prova, por isso sempre que utilizo algo novo em meus trabalhos procuro saber exatamente o que está acontecendo, se puder explique como fazer isso em CSS.

Comment: @Adrian, Alterei com um pouco mais de informação. Está claro assim?

Comment: Ótimo, as primeiras opções em que você explicou fiquei sem entender, pois a única coisa que sei sobre CSS até o momento é que existem 3 formas para usar, porém irei testar a última agora mesmo para ver. Obrigado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu desejava, já ganhou meu respeito. *-*

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
    text-indent: 2em;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

Comment: Ta um pouquinho atrasado, só um pouco.